# Calculating second moment of inertia for a region

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, regions

Let's say I want to calculate the moment of inertia of a half circle around its centroid. I set up a function to calculate the inertial moment like so:

```
inertialMoment[reg_?RegionQ, axis_InfiniteLine] := 
 Module[{df = RegionDistance[axis]}, 
  Integrate[df[{x, y}], {x, y} \[Element] reg]]
```

and then define my geometry as follows:

```
yc = RegionCentroid[Disk[{0, 0}, r, {0, Pi}]][[2]]
axis = InfiniteLine[{{-1, yc}, {1, yc}}];
```

So now I do

```
inertialMoment[Disk[{0, 0}, r, {0, Pi}], axis]
```

and I get:

[image]

Now, I think I understand what the message says, and my function works fine if I use a fixed axis, such as

```
axis = InfiniteLine[{-1, 0}, {1, 0}];
```

but it doesn't make much sense to have this restriction to an explicitly defined location for this axis. Is there a way around this?

P.S.: I know I can get moments of inertia using the `MomenOfInertia` function; the above is just an example.

Comment: You can actually do this: `df[{x_, y_}] = RegionDistance[axis, {x, y}]`  ( the integral is not returning now, but that's a different issue )

Comment: @george2079: Perhaps I'm missing something, but with your definition of `df` I get an error message about how "only assignments to symbols are allowed".

Comment: Did you mean to write `InfiniteLine[{{-1, yc}, {1, yc}}]` (with an extra `{}`)?  This gives a line through the two points specified.

Comment: @Mikado: Ah, yes, you're right. Fixed my post, but the change makes no difference in the outcome.

Comment: for my def you need to take the `df[]` definition out of the module init `{..}` into the module body..    I needed to do `$Assumptions={r>0}` for `yc` to come out right by the way.

Comment: Alright, I see now. Thanks!

Comment: Wait...I failed to notice my `df` gives a patently wrong result for the distance (!)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can reasonably expand the definition of `RegionDistance` to cover this case:

```
Unprotect[RegionDistance];
RegionDistance[InfiniteLine[{u_List, v_List}]] := Function[{x},
  Module[{p, d},
   p = Normalize[u - v];
   d = x - u;
   Norm[d - (p.d) p]]]
Protect[RegionDistance];
```

This then allows you to evaluate the expressions you gave without problem

```
inertialMoment[reg_?RegionQ, axis_InfiniteLine] := 
 Module[{df = RegionDistance[axis]}, 
  Integrate[df[{x, y}], {x, y} ∈ reg]]

yc = RegionCentroid[Disk[{0, 0}, r, {0, Pi}]][[2]]
axis = InfiniteLine[{{-1, yc}, {1, yc}}];
(* (4 r)/(3 π) *)
```

And it now works with symbolic `r`

```
Assuming[r > 0, inertialMoment[Disk[{0, 0}, r, {0, Pi}], axis]]
(* (4 (8 Sqrt[-16 + 9 π^2] r^3 + 
   9 π^2 Sqrt[-16 + 9 π^2] r^3 - 
   54 π^2 r^3 ArcSec[(3 π)/4]))/(81 π^3) *)
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In 2016, the function `MomentOfInertia[]` has been introduced.

Comment: Yep, as I had mentioned in my 2016 post, along with the fact that this was not the point of my question.

Comment: Point taken. Anyway, I found this question looking for this functionality, so the hint may be useful for others.